# google drive moving files into folders - iterator has reached the end

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive-api

I wrote a little code, it should grab all files in a folder and one by one put into a folder based on the first 10 character of the filename. If no folder with the name, creates one.
Its working, but randomly stops with an error. (see pic below)

What really strange is, if i restarting it, it continues and after a couple of restarts it can finish the job.
Why is it randomly stopping?
Could you help me with this please? Its driving me crazy.

Thank you in advance.

```
function sort() {
  
  var inputFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById("thefolderid12343434343");

  var files = inputFolder.getFiles();
  let folders = inputFolder.getFolders();
  let folderNames = [];

  while (folders.hasNext()) {
    var folder = folders.next();
    folderNames.push(folder.getName());
  }

  while (files.hasNext()) {

    var file = files.next();
    var fileName = file.getName();
    var destinationFolderName = fileName.substring(0,10); //for x characters

    if (folderNames.includes(destinationFolderName)) {
    
      var destinationFolderId =inputFolder.getFoldersByName(destinationFolderName).next().getId();
      var processedFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById(destinationFolderId);
      file.moveTo(processedFolder);

    } else {

      let newFolder = inputFolder.createFolder(destinationFolderName);
      let destinationFolderId = newFolder.getId();
            try{
        var processedFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById(destinationFolderId);
      file.moveTo(processedFolder);
      }
      catch(error){
        Logger.log(destinationFolderName);
      }
      folderNames.push(destinationFolderName);
      
    }
    
  
  }

}
```

[image: error code]

[image: runtimes]

Comment: Could you include a sample structure of files in your drive which we can replicate to test your code? Also, have you tried adding `hasNext()` to check if the folder exist this line of code `var destinationFolderId = inputFolder.getFoldersByName(destinationFolderName).next().getId();`?

Answer (score 0):

Nor sure if it's the cause of the error but I suspect you can simplify the code a bit.

Instead of this:

```
var destinationFolderId =inputFolder.getFoldersByName(destinationFolderName).next().getId();
      var processedFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById(destinationFolderId);
      file.moveTo(processedFolder);
```

You can use this:

```
var processedFolder = inputFolder.getFoldersByName(destinationFolderName).next();
file.moveTo(processedFolder);
```

Perhaps it helps if you won't call `DriveApp` here. And the same thing in the `else` branch.

I haven't tried the code, I can be wrong.

Comment: Thanks, i replaced this part of the code. Sadly the error message still occurring.

Answer (score 0):

I noticed that this line of code does not have `hasNext()` to check if the folder/s exist.

```
if (folderNames.includes(destinationFolderName)) {
  var destinationFolderId =inputFolder.getFoldersByName(destinationFolderName).next().getId();
  var processedFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById(destinationFolderId);
  file.moveTo(processedFolder);
}
```

Usually, `Exception: Cannot retrieve the next object: iterator has reached the end.` occurs when the Iterator can't find the item in the folder or the folder is empty.

Instead, try enclosing it with an if-statement with `hasNext()`:

```
if(inputFolder.getFoldersByName(destinationFolderName).hasNext()){
   var destinationFolderId = inputFolder.getFoldersByName(destinationFolderName).next().getId();
   var processedFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById(destinationFolderId);
   file.moveTo();
}
```

**Note:** Using `inputFolder.getFoldersByName(destinationFolderName).next().getId();` directly without iteration will only get the id of the first folder that matches the `destinationFolderName` name.

### Reference:

- [FolderIterator](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/folder-iterator)

Comment: I still dont get it.
The folder should be there because, 1. step, get the folder names, if the searched folder is in this list, then put the file there, if not create a folder and put into the new folder.
So the if condition only triggering if the folder is there, but still i got the error message, that is not true.

Answer (score 0):

Not the best practice, rather a clumsy crutch... Try to use `try/catch` here:

```
try {
  var destinationFolderId =inputFolder.getFoldersByName(destinationFolderName).next().getId();
  var processedFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById(destinationFolderId);
  file.moveTo(processedFolder);
} catch(e) {}
```

And see what happens.

If there are some glitches on the server and it skips some files/folders with no reason, you can try to make a workaround. Something like this:

```
var glitched_folders = [];

try {
  var destinationFolderId =inputFolder.getFoldersByName(destinationFolderName).next().getId();
  var processedFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById(destinationFolderId);
  file.moveTo(processedFolder);
} 
catch(e) {
  glitched_folders.push(destinationFolderName);
}
```

And then repeat the function for the `glitched_folders`.

---

And, given the timestamps from the log, I suspect you have hundreds files. So it makes sense to minimize all redundant operations.

For example, you don't need to get ID of folders if you already had the folder-object. You can store the folder objects in array and use them:

```
var files = inputFolder.getFiles();
let folders = inputFolder.getFolders();
let folderNames = [];
let folderObjects = []; // <-------------- here

while (folders.hasNext()) {
  var folder = folders.next();
  folderNames.push(folder.getName());
  folderObjects.push(folder);  // <-------------- here
}
```

And then (one call to the server):

```
var index = folderNames.indexOf(destinationFolderName);
if (index > -1) { file.moveTo(folderObjects[index]) }
```

instead of (three calls to the server):

```
if (folderNames.includes(destinationFolderName)) {
  var destinationFolderId =inputFolder.getFoldersByName(destinationFolderName).next().getId();
  var processedFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById(destinationFolderId);
  file.moveTo(processedFolder);
}
```

...etc.